# Getting AttributeError: module 'matplotlib._image' has no attribute 'frombyte' in python3

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to execute a simple snippet of code which is given below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = caffe.io.load_image(root + 'images/cat.jpg')
transformed_image = transformer.preprocess('data', image)
plt.imshow(image)
```

When the code reaches `plt.imshow`, I'm faced with the following error :

```
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib._image' has no attribute 'frombyte'
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x1bd2ac8ac18>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: What is `caffe` and `transformer`? Mind that questions about errors should have the complete error traceback and a  [mcve] to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I just upgraded the matplotlib and the error is gone! this miyght have been  caused by missing dependency or even a corrupted module which ultimately got fixed by upgrading the matplotlib to the latest version.
(Caffe and transformer are python module and preprocessing class for Caffe framework respectively)

Comment: @importanceOfBeingErnest: 
By the way that was the minimal complete example. you can remove caffe related part and use any method for reading an image. and it would do the same,  the same error would be issued.
(un)fortunately the error got fixed by upgrading, and I cant reproduce that error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to the latest version of matplotlib and the issue is solved.